# Overflow: hidden adding padding to left and right side of the page

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to implement a grid onto [this](https://barkingmouse.com.au/231203816175-2/) page. Because the Wordpress page uses overflow:hidden to the layout it will need to remain as is.

Out of curiosity, I tried

```
.content-container, .content {
overflow:visible
```

To see if it will reveal the entire grid that was cut off and it did, but also revealed what I am trying to hide through the layout, a spare bit of page.

Is there any way that I can reveal the whole grid without having to allow the overflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cuts off the sides because `.container`'s width is set to a fixed value of `1170px`. 
 If you set `.container`'s width to 100% all content will be stretched.

```
.page-id-2099 .container {
width: 100%;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that has definitely made a difference. I had to update the code to include overflow:hidden as I was seeing a [x-overflow](https://imgur.com/gcg2GPf).

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
  .page-id-2099 .content-container, .page-id-2099 .content 
  {
      overflow: visible !important;
  }
```